# how can i update the items at html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

```
let bricks = document.querySelectorAll(".brick");
    bricks.forEach((brick) => {
      brick.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let bricktype = brick.getAttribute("type");
        console.log(bricktype);
      });
    });
```

from the above code ...

bricks variable get updated while the page first load. then i have form to add extra items to the bricks variable.. but i can't get update it .. if i try to reload page all the value eraes from memory

i want add values to that brocks array while i dynamicall add values in the html page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that code will only be executed at page load. This is a design problem, try refactoring your system some like this:

First, a function to add a listener for a single brick

```js
function setupBrick(brick) {
  brick.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let bricktype = brick.getAttribute("type");
    console.log(bricktype);
  });
}
```

Now, in first page load:

```js
let bricks = document.querySelectorAll(".brick");

bricks.forEach((brick) => {
  setupBrick(brick)
});
```

And when user dynamically push a brick, do the following:

```js
// get brick from form and store it in the "brickToPush" variable

setupBrick(brickToPush) // before push the brick
bricks.push(brickToPush)
```

That should solve your problem, you need to manually add that listener somehow, and encapsulating that logic in a function is a good practice